# handle legend in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

color_legend = { "c 1 :": "blue", "c 2:":"green", "c 3:":"red"}

f = plt.figure(1)
ax = f.add_subplot(1,1,1)
for label in color_legend:
    ax.plot([0],[0],color=color_legend[label],label=label)
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.show()
```

My question is: what exactly are the first two parameters [0] and [0] doing over there? Hope this is not a trivial question.

Comment: They are x and y coordinate points of the line you are plotting. See [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) for more arguments and better yet experiment with it.

Comment: @umutto, I do not understand. If so, in the example, all the three lines should be drawn overlapped, right?

Comment: @umutto, so, in this case, ax.plot should also be able to draw something in the figure, right? While if I comment the line "plt.legend(loc="best")", the legend is not shown. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code from the question draws 3 line plots. However, because a line needs two points to exist and you only supply a single point (`x=[0], y=[0]`), it's not shown on the canvas.

You have two options:

1. Provide more points, `ax.plot([0,2,3],[0,11,5])`
2. Show the point of the line as a dot, `ax.plot([0],[0], marker="o")`

The command `plt.legend(loc="best")` places a legend in the plot. If you ommit it, there will be no legend.